# Complexity of combination method

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I have a question about complexity of combination two methods. Assume that I have method A with its complexity is $O(n)$ and second method that has complexity is $O(n^2)$. In which, n is number of elements that need resolve.

This is my problem: To resolve n elements, I must use two methods: 1 and 2. Assume that after use method 1, we can resolve $n_1$ elements in total of $n$ elements, so the complexity of first step is $O(n_1)$. The remaining unresolve is $(n-n_1)$. We must apply method 2, therefore, the complexity of second step is $O((n-n_1)^2)$

**The total complexity is $O(n_1)+O((n-n_1)^2)$**

Is it correct?

Note that: $n_1$ will be increasing when $n$ is large.

Comment: Hint: Big Oh is about asymptotics. What happens when n is large?

Comment: n around $100$ to $10000$. When n is large. the problem is similar the $O(n^2)$. However, in this case, I only consider n is small about 1000. Note that, $n_1$ will increase when n is increase

Comment: @user_of_math: How about my answer?

Comment: If $n_1 \ge n - \sqrt{n}$ then the total complexity will be $O(n)$. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank HeKto. However, I want to verify my answer about complexity of combination method. Is just plus two complexity of them?

Comment: @mjohn1282 - no, it's very unusual to present an algorithm complexity as a sum of two $O$'s. If you have two parameters, describing the algorithm, then try to find a single function *of these two parameters* and use it inside the $O$.